# Pick up lines from a file based on line numbers in another file

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have two files - one contains the addresses (line numbers) and the other one data, like this:

address file:

```
2
4
6
7
1
3
5
```

data file

```
1.000451451
2.000589214
3.117892278
4.479511994
5.484514874
6.784499874
7.021239396
```

I want to randomize the data file based on the numbers of address files
so I get:

```
2.000589214
4.479511994
6.784499874
7.021239396
1.000451451
3.117892278
5.484514874
```

I want to do it either in python or in bash, but didn't yet find any solution.

Comment: Does the address file contains line number or the `int`s of numbers from the data file?

Comment: Only line numbers

Comment: `I want to do it either in python or in bash` then try something and add the code in question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} {print a[$0]}' data.txt addr.txt
```

- `NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next}` creates an associative array `a` with keys being the record (line) number and values being the whole record, this would be applicable only for the first file (`NR==FNR`), which is `data.txt`. `next` makes `awk` to go to the next line without processing the record any further
- `{print a[$0]}` prints the value from the array with keys being the currect file's (`addr.txt`) line (record) number

**Example:**

```
% cat addr.txt 
2
4
6
7
1
3
5

% cat data.txt 
1.000451451
2.000589214
3.117892278
4.479511994
5.484514874
6.784499874
7.021239396

% awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} {print a[$0]}' data.txt addr.txt
2.000589214
4.479511994
6.784499874
7.021239396
1.000451451
3.117892278
5.484514874
```

Comment: Nice solution and great explanation.

Comment: Very flexible use in awk.

Comment: nice quality answer with explanation for future use. PS :I didn't DV.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind `sed`, we can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) to achieve this easily:

```
sed -nf <(sed 's/$/p/' addr.txt) data.txt
```

- `-n` suppresses the default printing
- `-f` makes `sed` read commands from the process substitution `<(...)`
- `<(sed 's/$/p/' addr.txt)` creates `sed` print commands based on line numbers in `addr.txt`

Gives the output:

```
2.000589214
4.479511994
6.784499874
7.021239396
1.000451451
3.117892278
5.484514874
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, also, within `Python`, like this example:

```
with open("address_file", 'r') as f1, open("data_file", "r") as f2:
    data1 = f1.read().splitlines()
    data2 = f2.read().splitlines()

for k in data1:
    # Handle exceptions if there is any
    try:
        print(data2[int(k)-1])
    except Exception:
        pass
```

**Edit:** As suggested @heemayl, here is another solution using only one `list`:

```
with open("file1", 'r') as f1, open("file2", 'r') as f2:
    data = f2.read().splitlines()

    for k in f1.read().splitlines():
        print(data[int(k)-1])
```

**Both will output:**

```
2.000589214
4.479511994
6.784499874
7.021239396
1.000451451
3.117892278
5.484514874
```

Comment: You don't need to have two lists. Just create the list for datafile and iterate over the lines for the file with just line numbers.

Comment: Yes, i know. But i think it's easy for the OP to catch whats happening inside the code. I do'nt think he had a good knowledge how to answer his question using Python. But still your comment is correct.